# How to fetch img srcset url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image tag with srcset attribute holding a value(url). Now i need to fetch and generate same for src attribute as well.

```
$('img').attr('srcset')
```

The above code is not working and returns undefined.

```
<img srcset="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Hod/Mobile600x160?$600x160$" alt="">
```

I need to fetch above srcset value("http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Hod/Mobile600x160?$600x160$") and append the same value for src attribute. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just need to do something with the 'srcset' value, the answer already provided are just fine. But if your purpose is to change the image 'src' through javascript, you should consider to apply the HTML Specification [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-img-srcset) the specification, and [here](https://responsiveimages.org/) a small explanation that suggest to use 'srcset' in combination with 'sizes' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait till the dom is loaded: `$(document).ready(function(){})`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = $('.img');
  img.each(function(){
    this.src = this.srcset;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="img" srcset="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Hod/Mobile600x160?$600x160$" alt="">
<img class="img" srcset="http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Hod/Mobile600x160?$600x160$" alt="">
```

you still can change back to `$('img')` instead of `$('.img')` but be aware that then every img tag will be progressed.

Comment: A simple `this.src = this.srcset` would be enough. No need to instantiate two fullblown jQuery objects just for reading and assigning an attribute value :)

Comment: $('img').prop('srcset') returns " "

Comment: @vsm if you hit run you will see that the img src is assigned, did you add the document-ready part ?

Answer (score 2):

use this it works for me ! 
as XzenTorXz said in above with a little change :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img = $('img[srcset]');
  img.each(function(){
    this.src = $(this).attr('srcset');
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work with multiple images (see the OPs comment)

Comment: No it doesn't. `.attr(...)` returns the value of the first element in the set of matched elements. With this code every image will have the same `src` value (namely the `srcset` from the first image)

Comment: hi @Saeid, I need to update all img tags. Need to get srcset value and update that value to src attribute

Comment: @vsm plz check mine too plz this checks only img with attr srcset not all of imgs

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
  <img src="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-src.jpg" 
     srcset="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-1x.jpg 1x, 
             http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-2x.jpg 2x"
     alt="Germany"
     id="photo-full">

<div class="thumbs">
  <img src="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-src-thumb.jpg"
       srcset="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-1x-thumb.jpg 1x,
               http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-2x-thumb.jpg 2x"
       alt="Germany"
       data-full-src="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-src.jpg"
       data-full-srcset="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-1x.jpg 1x,
               http://jonathonleathers.com/images/germany-2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/hawaii-src-thumb.jpg"
       srcset="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/hawaii-1x-thumb.jpg 1x,
               http://jonathonleathers.com/images/hawaii-2x-thumb.jpg 2x"
       alt="Hawaii"
       data-full-src="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/hawaii-src.jpg"
       data-full-srcset="http://jonathonleathers.com/images/hawaii-1x.jpg 1x,
               http://jonathonleathers.com/images/hawaii-2x.jpg 2x">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $src = $(this).attr('data-full-src');
    var $srcset = $(this).attr('data-full-srcset');
    var $alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#photo-full').attr('src', $src);
    $('#photo-full').attr('srcset', $srcset);
    $('#photo-full').attr('alt', $alt);
```

for refrence http://codepen.io/jtleathers/pen/IGytf

Comment: What's with all these unnecessary attributes and their values?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var srcset = jQuery(this).attr('srcset');
    var alt = jQuery(this).attr('alt');
    alert(srcset);
    jQuery('.images .zoom .wp-post-image').attr('src', src);
    jQuery('.images .zoom .wp-post-image').attr('srcset', srcset);
    jQuery('.images .zoom .wp-post-image').attr('alt', alt);
  });
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged as they don't help anyone who might stumble upon this answer other than the OP. Please see [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), as well as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) to see why this is the case and what constitutes a good answer. Maybe add some explanation as to what this code does.

Comment: sorry for that but an average programmer can easily understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get array of URLs from multiple images from "srcset":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //all photos with srcset attribute
  let photos = jQuery(".photos source")

  //iterate to get urls from the set
  let urls = jQuery.map(photos, function (el) {

     //get srcset attribute from the tag
     const rawUrls = jQuery(el).attr('srcset');

     //strip all unnecessary data from the attribute
     const urlsArray = rawUrls.replace(/\s+[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[wx]/g, "").split(/,/);   

     const lastUrlIndex = urlsArray.length - 1;

     //get the last (largest) url from the set for each image
     return urlsArray[lastUrlIndex].trim()
  })

  console.log(urls);

});
```